# How do you have vim find or search for a file in the path when opening a split?

Tags: vim

In vim, I can find a file and open it in a new tab using `:tabfind`, and I can open a file I know the location of in a new split using `:split` or `:vsplit`.  However, I would like vim to find files for me in my path when running the `:split` or `:vsplit` commands.  For example, say in my current directory, I have these files (all of which are in my path):

```
./ReallyLongFileName1.txt
./fooDir/ReallyLongFileName2.txt
./barDir/bazDir/ReallyLongFileName3.txt
```

I would like to type the following command in vim:

```
:vsplit R<Tab>
```

And have vim search in my path for all files that match that expression, and fill the rest of the line with

```
:vsplit ReallyLongFileName
```

This works perfectly with `:find` or `:tabfind`, but it doesn't work when splitting.  Is there a command that does this that I just don't know about, or is there some way to add this functionality to the `:split` and `:vsplit` commands?

Comment: My install of Vim 7.3 does this, and I don't think I had to change any settings. Could you tell us the version of your Vim installation?

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov 11 2010 14:49:38)
Included patches: 1-55

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As romainl said, `:sf` is the command that performs this action.  There is no vertical split find, although you can do the same thing with the slightly longer command `:vert sf`.

Answer (score 8):

Typing `:split | :find<space>R` (meaning "open a split then find..." seems to do the trick. Same thing with `:vsplit`.

Making it a custom function and calling it with a `nnoremap` would make it even better.

Edit:

I didn't know about `:find` and `:tabfind` so I looked them up in Vim's help and I found `:sfind` which does exactly one of the things you want. Unfortunately I don't see a `:vfind` or `:vsfind`.

Look it up: `:help sfind`.

Answer (score 3):

what I do for vertical split find is: add an abbreviation in .vimrc.

```
" Abbreviation for vertical split find
cabbrev vsf vert sfind
```